# How to use bootstrap in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just used create-react-app and ive been trying to use bootstrap. it doesnt work even after I npm install it.what should i do step by step [This is my app do i need to write a "import" line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU7hs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this link on your browser https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html
Copy the bootstrap CDN link under the stylesheet section and add it to you index.html file in your your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to reference the files in your app. You can add the necessary `<link .../>` and `<script ...></script>` tags in your index.html file.

You could also look into using something like the `react-bootstrap` npm package instead.